# EntityFramework 5.0 Cant save object with childs using SaveContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a base object with common properties:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
    {
        [Required]
        public  User ModifiedUser { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User CreatedUser { get; set; }
    }
```

All other objects inherit form the above but when I try to save using the SaveContext it doesn't work with error:
ModifiedUser - The ModifiedUser field is required.
CreatedUser - The CreatedUser field is required.

Category object:

```
public class Category : BaseItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
...
   }
```

Method for saving category:

```
public List<Category> SaveCategories(Category[] categories)
        {
            try
            {
                using (EntityContext context = new EntityContext())
                {
                    context.Category.AddOrUpdate(categories);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                ...
            }
 catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
...
}
}
```

I used AddOrUpdate() but I also tried to get a category from database first and then call the context.SaveChanges(); but I get the same error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

### ## Update ##

I guess I spotted why this is happening. The problem is with the BaseItem, which is the base class of all other classes where I have ModifiedUser and CreatedUser. Well I also have a User class which inherits from baseitem. So now I am facing a circular dependency between BaseItem and User. 
Or maybe in this case since User inherits from BaseItem, we have a Circular Dependency on a self-referencing object.

```
public class User : BaseItem
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to make the ModifiedUser and CreatedUser as virtual but I have WCF and it wont serialize.

Comment: How do you set `ModifiedUser` and `CreatedUser`?

Comment: I am still in the testing phase so I just pull all categories, change a value and then save them back to database.

Answer (score 0):

Are ModifiedUser and CreatedUser null on each category object in the categories array?  They cannot be null since you marked them as Required.

Comment: You are right they cannot be null. But for some reason they are not assigned in my context.